# how to convert from a datetime picker in DevExpress in C# to DateTime only date without time

Tags: c#, sql, visual-studio

[image]I need the result as
01/05/1998
not
01/05/1998 07:35PM

I tried
`(Convert.ToDateTime(DateTime.Parse(dtpCUST_BD.EditValue.ToString()).ToShortDateString())`

Comment: DateTimes have no format; the format is applied when printing/converting to string. If you don't save the result of `ToShortDateString()`, that call does nothing. Show how you print the value.

Comment: `var date = dtpCUST_BD.EditValue.Date;` to get rid of time part; if you want a string `var result = dtpCUST_BD.EditValue.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy");`

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: If my opinion is helpful to you, you can mark it so that it can help more people

Answer (score 0):

If you use `DateTime.Parse(dtpCUST_BD.EditValue.ToString()).ToShortDateString()` directly, it will display `01/05/1998`, of course it is a string type. But you added `Convert.ToDateTime()` outside, which caused the string that had already been converted into a short date type to be converted into a `DateTime` type by you. However, as long as it is a `DateTime` type, it will have a date + time, so The result becomes `01/05/1998 0:00:00`.

The code you provided is correct, but one is missing)
The correct one should be like this:

```
(Convert.ToDateTime(DateTime.Parse(dtpCUST_BD.EditValue.ToString()).ToShortDateString())).
```

Also, here's an easy way to get only the date of DateTime data:

```
DateTime datetime = new DateTime(1998,01,05,19,35,00);
 
var date = date.Date;
```

The opinions in the comment area are also correct.

Maybe you already know these things, but there is a misunderstanding here. That is, no matter what method is currently used, as long as you want to display DateTime type data, it is impossible to display only the date. It only makes sense to display only the date when it is converted to a String type.

**Second update:**

For your new question, I tried to insert DateTime data directly into the date attribute of sqlserver and it was successful. And using the following code to convert DateTime to string type and insert it into the date attribute of sqlserver is still successful.

```
         DateTime dateTime = DateTime. Now;
         string date = dateTime.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd");
         Dao dao = new Dao();
         string sql = $"insert into Date values('{date}')";
         dao. Execute(sql);
```

Because the date format you want to convert is dd-MM-yyyy, so there is a problem with the conversion when inserting into the database

Comment: thanks for your response but I tried the code you mention its stills add the time to date , In Sql server I set the datatype of birthday to date not datetime but when I need to insert the birthday still asks me to convert to datetime

Comment: @SamerKasseb I updated the new answer for your new question, if it is helpful to you, you can mark it so that it can help more people